# Was The Dude wearing Donny's bowling shirt?

Tags: costume, the-big-lebowski

In [*The Big Lebowski*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118715/), Donny is always shown wearing a bowling shirt bearing different names (which are never his own name):

[image: Donny]

When The Dude and Walter are at the funeral home making the necessary arrangements for Donny's funeral, The Dude is shown wearing a bowling shirt bearing the name "Art" on it (which is obviously not his name):

[image: dude]

**Is there any evidence from filmmakers that The Dude is wearing one of Donny's bowling shirts?  Was this some kind of memorial to Donny?**

Comment: What about the size difference of the shirt? Obviously Dude may need much bigger shirt than Donny

Comment: It's not that much of a different size and Donny's shirts are really loose fitting.  I could understand if Walter was wearing the shirt, but it's not that much of a stretch for The Dude to wear one of his shirts, imo.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4236/49).

Answer (score 5):

Donny's full name was Theodore Donald Kerabatsos.

According to a local [newspaper](https://www.ohio.com/akron/entertainment/the-heldenfiles-local-lebowski-lore#/) in Akron, Ohio, the "Medina Sod" bowling shirt The Dude wears in the movie is a real 1960s bowling shirt found in a thrift store in Los Angeles. It belonged to a man named Art Myers, who was the foreman at Medina Sod in Medina, Ohio.

Comment: That explains why the shirt has that name IRL, but neither confirms nor denies whether it's also a reference to Donny.  I wouldn't be surprised if they're all vintage shirts.